# How does IOTA solved the FLP impossibility?

Tags: consensus

[FLP impossibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)#Solvability_results_for_some_agreement_problems) states that:

No deterministic consensus protocol can guarantee safety, liveness and fault tolerance in an asynchronous system.

What is the problem of this statement, and how does IOTA prevented this problem using its consensus mechanism?

Comment: Isn't the consensus probabilistic, not deterministic?

Comment: Thanks a lot CfB. That's what I thought as well. So actually all permissionless DLT (including Blockchain) are asynchronous so their consensus is probablistic in nature?